# Validating input and Word Count in C#

Tags: c#, input, count, cpu-word

I have to do an C program which need to run in UBuntu system. For different number of words for command I input will give different print outs. Moreover, specific words in specific positions 
would also give different print outs
for example:

```
root@linux:~# ./recover
Usage: ./recover -d [device filename] [other arguments]
-i Print boot sector information
-l List all the directory entries
-r filename [-m md5] File recovery with 8.3 filename
-R filename File recovery with long filename

root@linux:~# ./recover -d fat32.disk -i
Number of FATs = 2
Number of bytes per sector = 512
Number of sectors per cluster = 8
Number of reserved sectors = 32
Number of allocated clusters = 1000
Number of free clusters = 8000
```

Now The code i have already done:

```
int main () {
    int argc;
    char *argv[50];
    char deviceFilename[512];
    char recoverFilename[512];
    int i, j;
    while (1)
    {

        if (argc < 4 || argc == 6 || argc > 7)
        {
            printUsage(argv[0]);
        }
        else if (strcmp("-i", argv[3]) == 0 || strcmp("-l", argv[3]) == 0)
        {
            if (argc > 4)
                printUsage(argv[0]);
            else if (argc == 4 && (strcmp("-i", argv[3]) == 0))
            {
                strcpy(deviceFilename, argv[2]);
                if (initDisk(deviceFilename))
                {
                    printInfo();
                    fclose(fp);
                }
                else
                    printUsage(argv[0]);
            }
            else if (argc == 4 && (strcmp("-l", argv[3]) == 0))
            {
                strcpy(deviceFilename, argv[2]);
                if (initDisk(deviceFilename))
                {
                    listRootDir();
                    fclose(fp);
                }
                else
                    printUsage(argv[0]);
            }
        }
        else if (strcmp("-r", argv[3]) == 0)
        {
            if (argc == 4)
                printUsage(argv[0]);
            else
            {
                if (argc == 7 && strcmp("-m", argv[5]) == 0)
                {
                    strcpy(deviceFilename, argv[2]);
                    strcpy(recoverFilename, argv[4]);
                    printUsage(argv[0]);
                }
                else if (argc == 5)
                {
                    strcpy(deviceFilename, argv[2]);
                    strcpy(recoverFilename, argv[4]);
                    if (initDisk(deviceFilename))
                    {
                        if (checkMatch(argv[4]) == 1)
                            recover(argv[4]);
                        fclose(fp);
                    }
                    else
                        printUsage(argv[0]);
                }
                else
                    printUsage(argv[0]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printUsage(argv[0]);
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

./recover is one word and ./recover -d fat32.disk -i are 4 words.
also my program need to wait users input again and again.
So I think it needs a while loop to access it.
I know little about the implementation to get input from users.
However I confused to implement the word count and also the while loop at the same time.
Actually I complete the check condition work and other functions.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can take a look at the "Command Line Parser Library" https://commandline.codeplex.com/

Comment: Every time I see something like `else printUsage(argv[0]); } else printUsage(argv[0]); } } else { printUsage(argv[0]);`, my eyes hurt

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `Console.ReadLine()` and `Console.ReadKey()`. For input parameters there are two ways to access them.

- One way is to use the args array that is a parameter of your Main function (first entry is always the name of your executeable).
- Use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` same as before, the first entry is always the name of your executable.

Something like this should do:

```
string currentInputToHandle = string.Join("", Environment.GetCommandLineArgs());   
do
{        
    HandleEnteredArgument(currentInputToHandle);        
    currentInputToHandle = Console.ReadLine();
}while(currentInputToHandle.ToLowerInvariant() != "exit".ToLowerInvariant())
```

**edit**

You should probably restructure your sanitation stuff. I guess the easiest would be to `string.Split("-")` the supplied arguments, that way you'd have the command and all of it's parameters in one string, after that check for the amount of arguments by doing a `string.Split(" ")`. That should enhance the readability of your code by a great margin.

**edit2**
oh, I totally forgot that one command could depend on the other command, so I removed the foreach part.

Comment: +1 for answering the question in the context of the subject and the tags.

Comment: I thought it(the question) was pretty straight forward ;). Thanks, though.

Comment: sorry, but where should i put my condition checking part? or simply my code is useless?

Comment: @user2820453 in the HandleEnteredArgument method.

Comment: Can I just put your code directly to compile? or it just a relevant?

Comment: I'm not sure if I know what you mean. My code is more of a mock-up/an example but if it works for you, you can of course use it. It should compile if you put it inside a method and define the `HandleEnteredArgument` method.

Comment: After I read your answer, I know I miss a while loop for loop infinitely, and I can use Console.WriteLine() to wait the inputs from users.However, I don't know whether my condition checking is adaptable now, likes argv[3]==.... You said I should work in the HandleEnteredArguement method. I googled but nothing useful. May I ask what are the details?

Comment: Oh you mean The checking part should out of main function and call by HandleEnteredArguement?

Comment: So for checking for example, "-l" should be in the 2nd and 4th arguement, how can i implement?

Comment: well, I'd do it in 'nested' if statements, or if the option/flag is needed, I'd put that in the if statement that checks which argument was given

Comment: what is the library? I googled it is a window console but i need to compile in linux OS.

Comment: uhm it's in the System namespace so it's in the mscorlib.dll of .NET -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.console%28v=vs.110%29.aspx which is part of mono, so I'm not sure what your problem is?!